# Schedule a Perl script run in Ubuntu. Not looking at cron

Tags: perl, user-interface, cron, schedule

I've got this Perl script on Ubuntu that I need to run at a particular time in the future. I don't need it to run at that time more than once or basically what I'm trying to say is that it does not need a `cron`.

I need to schedule a run at a future time to run once and that's it. Any idea how to go about it? I've googled a bit but every time the concept of cron comes up so not really helpful.

I do have some code. The user clicks on a button (say "Schedule") on the GUI and a process starts in the background which schedules the run after (say) N hours.

I'm ready with the GUI and the connection to the backend Perl script. The N hours is predetermined. But I don't know how to code the scheduling concept in the Perl script.

Answer (score 2):

One way is that your Perl scripting will just `sleep(seconds)` and then execute the action. In case you don't want to have this you need to tell some other service that it should invoke a program at a specific time. In UNIX this is usually done with the [at command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `at` command:

```
echo 'perl foo.pl' | at now + 3 hours
```

Comment: I did try this out. when I execute my script like:

Comment: what happened?  and by the way, what language is your GUI?